# Rails code refactoring tool for Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, refactoring

I am looking for a refactoring tool for rails application in Mac. After researching for whole week I am kind of surprised that there is no good tool available to refactor namespace/controller/model/view/routes in one go. I am bit new to Mac paradigm so may be I am missing something.

I can see few couple of gems developed for Rails which can do some rename/replace but still it requires "manual adjustments" after refactor.

To provide my requirement, here is standard Rails projects

```
# routes
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :items
end
match "/admin/items/:id/enable" => "admin/items#enable"

# model
/app/models/items.rb
class item < ActiveRecord::Base

end

# views
/app/views/admin/items/
/app/views/admin/items/index.html.erb
/app/views/admin/items/show.html.erb
/app/views/admin/items/new.html.erb
/app/views/admin/items/edit.html.erb


# controller
/app/controllers/admin/items_controller.rb

class Admin::ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #
  end

  def show
    #
  end

  def enable
    #
  end
end
```

My requirement for this tool is very basic:

Refactoring: "item" to "product" - with case match

1. Tool should rename any file contains "item" to "product"
2. Tool should rename any folder contains "item" to "product"
3. Tool should find and replace "item" and to "product" in all files in current or sub directory.

With above feature:

I can simply reactor whole project by:

```
> refactor "item" "product"
> refactor "Item" "Product"
> refactor "admin" "shop"
> refactor "Admin" "Shop"
```

Greatly appreciate if you can help me to provide link of any Mac tool or any script which can fulfill my above requirement.

Comment: You might want to give ruby mine a try (Not used it myself but it claims support for stuff like refactoring)

Comment: Thanks Frederick. I did tried RubyMine and yes you can refactor class or method names with RubyMine but it still lack handling renaming folder name and routes maps (my #1 & #2 refactor requirement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I decided this sounded neat so I wrote a tool which seams to pull off what you want and I've decided to call it refacto.

Here's your quick read-me:

Proper Usage is: `refacto findString changeString <file extensions> <options>`

File extensions are not optional.  In order for any files to be renamed or refactored, you must list at least one file extension.  Folders will be renamed by default, if you don't want to rename them, use -nf.

Options:
  -a : Ask for confirmation to refactor or rename each file/folder.
  -nf : Do not rename folders or subfolders
  -ci : Case Insenitive.  Will change all versions of findString

Get the source code here: https://github.com/bpo217/refacto

A couple things to note:

Refacto changes ALL instances of findString in a file, not just a class name or anything like that.

Refacto will touch all subfolders and the files in those subfolders.

Since it's a tool after you compile it just put it into /usr/local/bin and whatever else you need to do so you can just type refacto anywhere in terminal to run it.  It will always work with the current working directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Blah I just realized you can't just make it work that easily.  I'll get you the source code tomorrow.

Comment: Wow! You are life saver. I didn't run your compiled code but this is exactly what I am looking for. Please do let me know if you release this tool on github.

Comment: Here's the github location: https://github.com/bpo217/refacto     Let me know if this helps!  I'll edit my main post.

Comment: Great job! Refacto is huge help to refactor large projects. Must-have tool for rails developers.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is not so easy to refactor, I believe.

If you don't want to do it **very often** nor at a **large scale**, then I would recommend simple Find in files and replace where needed. Yes it takes time but so does searching for a tool and learning it. And reviewing the changes of the tool afterwards if you want to be careful ;-)

*Sidenote*: Netbeans is my personal preference for such work due to it's search capabilities. Especially if you have it integrated with your source control (good pre-commit review). It's also fairly nice to you when you need to switch OS-es (like Mac) or programming languages.